# load image src into <img> using jQuery.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

On my site I would like to offer users the possibility to provide an image URL and then have that image load into a prepared `<img src="">` via AJAX.

This is the form including textbox and submit button:

```
<form id="myform">
  <input name="image_url" type="text" placeholder="type your image URL" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

and this would be the `<img>` tags:

```
<img src="" id="image_from_url">
```

I already have this jQuery statement in order to prevent the default submit button submission:

```
$(function () {

    $('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

    // ajax call here?

    });

  });
```

Can anybody give a hint on how I could include an ajax call here in order to load the image (from the image url the user provides in the form textbox) into the `<img src="">`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You dont need ajax here. Just `.prop()` would suffice.

Comment: @ShaunakD: Thanks! could you explain how to use this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Ajax for this. Simply grab the URL and create a new image element:

```
var i = null;
$('#capture_form').on('submit', function (event) {
    if (i) {
        // update image if it already exists
        i.prop('src', this.image_url.value);
    } else {
        // create <img>-element on the fly, as you might not need it beforehand
        i = $('<img/>', { src: this.image_url.value });
        // append it as a child to another element
        $('body').append(i);
    }

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/jf2u3nk9/)

Comment: thanks for your answer - however the `<img>` needs to be there even before the user provides a URL - can you edit? I believe instead of the two middle lines I would just write: `$("#image_from_url").attr("src", this.image_url.value);` ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution to create the element on the fly or update it if it already exists. If you have the `<img>`-element beforehand, simply use what you suggested instead: `$("#image_from_url").attr("src", this.image_url.value);`.

Answer (score 4):

Simply do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/vmvuny9e/

```
$(function () {
    $('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#image_from_url").attr("src", $("#image_url").val());
    });
});
```

No need for any AJAX calls, as you can just put the image URL into the `<img>`-tag's `src` attribute, and it will work flawlessly.

I added an ID to your input, as I needed to grab the value from it.

Comment: You could save one DOM request and you don't need the extra id. Simply use `this.image_url.value`. As you have the `form`-element already you can access its fields by their names with vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
var url = "Insert here the url";
$.get( url, function( data ) {
  $( "#image_from_url" ).attr('src', data );
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer - just one question: how do I "post" the URL into the variable in the first place?

Comment: It is recommended to use relative paths, to avoid problems as CORS, but it depends of your destination address,

Comment: `.src` method is not available to a jquery object, and it won't work.

Comment: Yes, my bad, you can use `.attr()`

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if I got it wrong, but I think you just want to load the image whenever user clicks on the submit button.
For that, you can write this in your submit button's code

```
$(function () {
  $('#capture_form').on('submit', function (e) {
    $('#capture_section').removeClass("hidden");
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#image_from_url').attr({src: "<Image URL here>"});
  });
});
```